# How to get multiple sub strings from string with delimiter # in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, string, typescript, substring

I have a string with multiple delimiters to change the string further.

How can I get those substrings?

Here is the string:

```
let string = 'Dear  user, 
Due to #userinput-reason#, your ward client will travel on #userinput-newtransit#
instead of the regular transit #userinput-regulartransit#.';
```

From the above string, I need set of all substrings in between `#` s.

Required output:

```
let substring = [ 'userinput-reason', 'userinput-newtransit', 'userinput-regulartransit' ]
```

Thank you.

```js
let str = 'Dear  user, Due to #userinput-reason#, your ward client will travel on #userinput-newtransit# instead of the regular transit #userinput-regulartransit#.';
let strings = [];
    let indexStart;
    let indexEnd;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (str[i] == '#') {
        indexStart = i + 1;
        if (indexStart >= 0) {
          for (let j = i + 1; j < str.length; j++) {
            if (str[j] == '#') {
              indexEnd = j ;
      let stringExtracted = str.substring(indexStart, indexEnd);
      strings.push(stringExtracted);            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(strings);
```

Comment: This seems like purely a [tag:javascript] problem, not specific to [tag:angular] or [tag:typescript]. What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I tried iterating through loop, but that is returning lot of loops. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Please give a [mre], then.

Comment: I have added code snippet in my question, is that helps?

Comment: What is the _problem_ with that snippet - what output do you get, and how does that compare with what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Do it with [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ZLoSJC/1):

```js
let a = 'Dear  user, Due to #userinput-reason#, your ward client will travel on #userinput-newtransit# instead of the regular transit #userinput-regulartransit#.';

let arr = a.match(/(?!#)(\w|-)+(?=#)/g);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = 'Dear  user, Due to #userinput-reason#, your ward client will travel on #userinput-newtransit# instead of the regular transit #userinput-regulartransit#.';
let strings = [];
let temp = "";
let append = false;
for(let i = 0; i< str.length; i++){
  if(append == true && str[i] !=  '#'){
    temp += str[i];
  }
  if(str[i] == '#' && append == false){
    // mark the starting of the token
    append = true;
  }
  else if (append == true && str[i] == "#"){
    // mark the end of the token
    append = false;
    strings.push(temp);
    temp = "";
  }
}
console.log(strings)
```